# How to automate a waveform which comes from a healthcare device?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, waveform, testcomplete

I am working as automation test engineer in healthcare. We have requirement for automating a waveform received from ECG which will be displayed in a web application. 
So is there any tool to automate the waveform ?

[WaveForm Sample IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Cb9.png)

Comment: Can you share screenshot which type of waveform?

Comment: @AnkurSingh Click on the WaveForm Sample IMAGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Sikuli**.

You have to be creative with it. As long as your application is running on any JVM supported platform and there is a feature to hold the waveform in a specific interval. Then , you can do image based assertion using Sikuli.

Answer (score 1):

Tough item to test, theoretically if the waveform isn't 'flattened' (i.e. just a picture) you should be able to pull out individual points. Image recognition is another option as the two images should match. It depends a lot on what you have to work with for data, if it's just a picture of a waveform you are pretty limited to just image based testing.

Comment: Click on the WaveForm Sample IMAGE